Codable: Decode a String into a custom type (ISO 8601 Date, no time components)
Consider the following type:
public struct DocumentDate: Codable {
    /// Year  component of the date, Integer with no limitation on the range.
    public let year: Int
    /// Month component of the date, Integer from 1 to 12.
    public let month: Int
    /// Day component of the date, Integer from 1 to 31.
    public let day: Int
}

What would be the easiest way to incorporate Codable and more specifically Decodable protocol support into this type to decode an ISO 8601-compliant date of type:
"2012-01-13"

Ideally, I'd like to get a String decoded in the initializer and then I'll be able to parse it as I wish. What would be the best strategy to implement this support?
I know I can use dateDecodingStrategy but that is to decode a String into Date. My type is actually not a Date, but a custom one, so that's where the challenge is.

you want to convert "2012-01-13" string  into DocumentDate and vice versa ?

As a part of JSON, so imagine a JSON where instead of a Date it should be converted into DocumentDate, so that's correct.

My suggestion is to implement init(from:) and parse the date string with Regular Expression
public struct DocumentDate: Decodable {
    /// Year  component of the date, Integer with no limitation on the range.
    public let year: Int
    /// Month component of the date, Integer from 1 to 12.
    public let month: Int
    /// Day component of the date, Integer from 1 to 31.
    public let day: Int
    
    public init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self)
        guard let match = dateString.wholeMatch(of: /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/)?.output else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "\(dateString) is not a valid date format")
        }
        year = Int(match.1)!
        month = Int(match.2)!
        day = Int(match.3)!
    }
}

and an example how to use it
let jsonString = """
{"date":"2012-01-13"}
"""

struct Test: Decodable {
    let date: DocumentDate
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Test.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

You can even check if month and day are in the valid range for example
let month = Int(match.2)!
guard (1...12).contains(month) else { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Month value \(month) is out of range") }
self.month = month


An alternative is to create a date with ISO8601DateFormatter and extract the desired date components
public struct DocumentDate: Decodable {
    /// Year  component of the date, Integer with no limitation on the range.
    public let year: Int
    /// Month component of the date, Integer from 1 to 12.
    public let month: Int
    /// Day component of the date, Integer from 1 to 31.
    public let day: Int
    
    public init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self)
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        formatter.formatOptions = .withFullDate
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "\(dateString) is not a valid date format")
        }
        let components = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
        year = components.year!
        month = components.month!
        day = components.day!
    }
}


Great suggestion. the singleValueContainer seems to be what I was looking for, thanks! I would replace the part with the Formatter and Calendar and use Scanner or similar solution to read the components.

Look into the edit history. My first suggestion was parsing the string with Regex.

Great, could you pls revert, so that I could approve that answer? that's a great idea.

Perfect, thanks so much. Actually there is no need to check the range, but your answer is very good.

Which swift version are you running? I cannot compile the code with the regular expression.

The newest (5.9) in Sonoma. This Regex syntax has been introduced in Swift 5.7

I had to rework your solution a little bit due to a need to support lower versions. My implementation uses Scanner but achieves a very similar result. Thanks a lot for your help.
